# JavaScript: Real-time data and graphics, what tool?

Tags: javascript

There are so many different tools concerning JavaScript. What are the best tools to create a website around real-time data and graphics?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of graphics? Most sites use jQuery ([http://jquery.com](http://jquery.com)) for UI.
For graphs try [grafico](http://grafico.kilianvalkhof.com/)

Comment: Use [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) for a graphing tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com) is a really professional-looking and extendable charts library. I've found no other pure-javascript lib that can compete (it's only my opinion, sorry for the others :-) )

We use it extensively in production, and it helps us producing nice real-time charts, and dynamic reports. And it's easy to use. Performance are nice on Chrome,Firefox & IE8, acceptable on IE7

Comment: You've forgot to mention HighCharts is non-free for commercial purposes. But I agree you can achieve pretty good [effects](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/03/jolokia-highcharts-jmx-for-human-beings.html) with it.

Comment: @Tomasz Good to mention it. We've had a reflexion about that. We wanted a free tool... then we bought a license :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Thejit](http://thejit.org/) is also a nice graphing/visualization library. It also supports updating graphs via the updateJSON() method. If you are using jQuery and want to plot something, have a look at [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).